# How to make table row fit screen width?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-tablelayout

I have problem that my Linear layout that contains Table Layout looks great in Android Studio, it fits screen width, but when I launch app on my phone, part of table layout is missing. Here are pictures and code:

This is how it looks in Android Studio
[image: This is how it looks in Android Studio]

This is on my phone, 2 rows are missing
[image: This is on my phone, 2 rows are missing]

My code:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView android:padding="5dip" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="Teams"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="MP"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="W"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="D"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="L"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="GF"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="GA"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="+/-"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="PTS"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/rus" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="RUSSIA"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ksa" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="SAUDI ARABIA"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/egy" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="EGYPT"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/uru" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="URUGUAY"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried everything I could find on internet and nothing solved my table layout width, it just doesn't fit my screen 
I tried with wrap_content , fill_parent and match_parent but nothing works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having these problems is because of the hard-coded padding.

The hard-coded padding is making your table longer than the screen's size.

Proof:

1. Go into your XML file and do a find/replace for "android:padding="5dip" and replace it with nothing
2. Build your project
3. The table's width appears fine.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't find a way to do it so I used ScrollView instead.

Comment: @searoth what if you wanted the table to be able to scroll horizontally as well as vertically if needed?!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```